# How to Display the Text contents of a text file in yii?

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

I am trying to display the contents of a  text file inside a div in my view. I found that in php

```
<?php
    $myfilename = "mytextfile.txt";
    if(file_exists($myfilename)){
      echo file_get_contents($myfilename);
    }
?>
```

this code can be used . Is there any such methods in Yii to display the contents inside a   text file?

### Update

This file is stored under components folder. It cannot be included inside the views section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[readfile()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

[file_get_contents](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

You can try these two functions. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are `renderFile()` method in CController class.
Put your text file somewhere at views/files and use that method like

```
$this->renderFile('/files/filename.txt');
```

Comment: If so where shoul I specify the pat of that text file ?

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes. My doubt is , if Iam using the above method , where should I specify the path of the $filename ?

Comment: Edited my answer. I have forgotten about that method completely.

Comment: Sorry is there any methods to access the text file from an outside folder (from components). This text file cannot be included inside the views folder.

Comment: In this case just use file_get_contents function. But still you can put your file inside views filder and access it via yii aliases, something like this $path = Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.views.files') . '/filename.txt';